# libgdx translate 3D world co-ordinates to 2D screen co-ordinates

Tags: matrix, 3d, libgdx

I want to get the 2D screen coordinates from 3D world co-ordinates of a 3d object.

Suppose a 3d object has a matrix4, defining its center of mass transform. I have a matrix4 called camera.combined related to libgdx camera.

Now, I want to draw an image on the screen, whose coordinates will be same as the center of mass coordinates, but in 2D screen world...

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps something like camera.project(Vector3) is required here. But I don't know how to use this function...

Comment: u can get uv from ur model and draw it with ur spritebatch

Comment: Thanks...
I managed it through camera.project method :)

Comment: @rayyan-riaz, could you answer your own Austin here please, it would be great for others to understand what it is you did (thanks)?

Comment: sorry, I have completely forgot what I did back then :(

Answer (score 1):

To get the 2D screen co-ords of a model (or any 3D position), you do something like the following in your render loop:-

```
Vector3 tmp = new Vector3();
model_instance.transform.getTranslation(tmp);
camera.project(tmp);
// 'tmp' now stores the screen coords, so you can use it as follows (for example):-
font.draw(batch2d, "My text", tmp.x, tmp.y);
```